# python-social-auth tutorial or project

Tags: python, django

social-auth (facebook) in django project, but I have a problem. Now I can loging by Facebook but account (email) must exist in User table. But I cannot log in when User not exist in db. Next question is about some good python-social-auth tutorial or maybe some body can show me some code how to do it. Ps I read official doc but I still have a problem

Comment: Loving by Facebook? What do you mean?

Comment: @Lotus92: Kind of like loving by the fireplace, but for the younger generation. :)

Comment: Check this example : https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/tree/master/examples/django_example . python-social-auth github:https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docs for python-social-auth have a section for Django: http://psa.matiasaguirre.net/docs/configuration/django.html.

By default, you will have separate Facebook users and separate Django users.

Note that your settings.py you should have something like this:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
  'social_auth.backends.facebook.FacebookBackend',
  'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

That means you have different backends creating different users.  You would have to do some work to synchronize them.